# Prevent SharePoint from sending emails when changing elements via API

Tags: soap, sharepoint-email, api

I'm about to remove attachments in around 10k list items via SOAP API,  how do I prevent email notifications about this?

Comment: Are you sending email through "Alert me" option or you have workflow for this?

Comment: I'd like to stop notifications to all users on attachment removal

Comment: Yes, its ok. But how email sending functionality is configured?

Comment: it sends emails to creator, assignee of the item and everyone who is subscribed  to the list's updates

Comment: are u want to stop emails only while deleting attachments and start it again once you deleted all attachments?

Comment: yes,  definitely. but I want every other action  to send  notification despite of my work with attachments

Comment: Why would you use an API if you need to delete all attachments? Just open the list in explorer view, browse to the list/attachments folder and delete all. Plus since this is quicker you could disable other notifications while you are doing this.

Comment: You can do this using a system account. Systems accounts dont send e-mail and not fire workflows.